# Working web3j.replayTransactionsObservable example

Tags: java, blockchain, ethereum, web3-java

I want to retrieve the transaction history between 2 blocks and I came upon this replay filter
To replay the individual transactions contained within a range of blocks:

```
Subscription subscription = web3j.replayTransactionsObservable( <startBlockNumber>, <endBlockNumber>) .subscribe(tx -> { ... });
```

However, I am unable to find any working example related of this filter. Can anyone just help in providing a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply getting access to the transaction objects is pretty straightforward:

```
Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService());

web3j.replayTransactionsObservable(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).subscribe(System.out::println));
```

will print out all of the transactions that have occurred on the peer node running on your localhost. Just change `System.out::println` to `tx -> //do something with tx` (`tx` is a `org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.EthBlock$TransactionObject`).

Note that this will only replay the history. You won't see any new transaction objects as blocks are added to the chain.

A more complicated example of using subscriptions comes if you want to do something like listen for specific events emitted. I've included an example of that below in case it helps. If you need help with a specific problem, please post questions with more details and sample code.

```
// Prints event emitted from a deployed contract
// Event definition:
// event MyEvent(address indexed _address, uint256 _oldValue, uint256 _newValue);
public static void eventTest() {
  try {
    Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService());

    Event event = new Event("MyEvent",
                            Arrays.asList(new TypeReference<Address>() {}),
                            Arrays.asList(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}, new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}));

    // Note contract address here. See https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/405
    EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, "6dd7c1c13df7594c27e0d191fd8cc21efbfc98b4");

    filter.addSingleTopic(EventEncoder.encode(event));

    web3j.ethLogObservable(filter).subscribe(log -> System.out.println(log.toString()));
  }
  catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually I want only the transaction details between 2 specific blocks, let's say block number 500 and 600. I used this code 


Web3j webj = Web3j.build(new HttpService());
        webj.replayTransactionsObservable(
                new DefaultBlockParameterNumber(500), new DefaultBlockParameterNumber(600))
                .subscribe(tx -> System.out.println(tx.getBlockNumber()+" "+tx.getHash() + " " + tx.getTo()));


But it doesn't start from the desired block number. Where am I wrong?

Comment: What are you seeing in your output? I've tested this with a block range using Ganache and it works just fine. If you're using one of the test networks instead of Ganache, you need to make sure your node is fully synced.

Comment: I was using geth testnet. However I'll try with ganache too and update here.

Comment: Can i connect to the ethereum mainnet by downloading ganache and connecting my dapp? Because i want to query the actual ethereum blockchain.

Comment: You wouldn’t use Ganache for that. You use it to run a development node (using it is quicker than using testnet because it instantly mines transactions). To use mainnet, you would use a fully synced client node (can use Geth or Parity for this), or you use a provider like Infura. Some providers have limitations in functionality, though.

Comment: Yeah since replay function won't work with infura, ultimately I had to resort to setting up an ethereum node. I will be synced soon. I started syncing 12 hours ago.